# not getting return value through function or method in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, return

in this program i am iterating the function and adding the result into the file it works fine, no issue whatsoever but when i am trying to take the value from the return of last call, it just return nothing even though the variable is not empty.because the else part only runs for a single time.

```
#this is an ipynb file so spacing means they are getting executed from different blocks
def intersection(pre,i=0,point=0,count=0,result=dt):
    index=-1
    prefer=[]
    # print(i)
    if(0<i):
        url = "../data/result.csv"
        result= pd.read_csv(url,names=["a","b","c","d","e"])

    if(i<len(pre)):
           for j in result[pre[i]]:
                index=index+1
                if(demand[pre[i]][1] >= j):
                    prefer.append(result.iloc[index,:])
           i=i+1
           file = open('../data/result.csv', 'w+', newline ='')     
           header = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)
            
            # writing data row-wise into the csv file
            writer.writeheader()
            
            # writing the data into the file
            with file:   
                write = csv.writer(file)
                write.writerows(prefer)
                count=count+1
                 # print(prefer,count) print the outputs step by step
            intersection(pre,i,point,count,result)
    else:
        print("Else Part",type(result))
        print(result)
        return result




#
 pre=["a","b","c"]
 rec=intersection(pre)
 print(rec)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhKAX.png)

it prints all the value of result from else part i have excluded it in snapshot because it was too vast and i have few fields here but it wil not effect, for the problem which i am getting... please answer if you know how can i take the value of result into rec.

Comment: The function only returns `result` as part of the `else` block. Maybe move it to the main body of the code so `result` is returned every time?

Comment: i want to return it only once when code runs for the last time. and at the last run it goes to else part but doesn't returns anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK. The code is a bit more complex than I thought. I was trying to work through it just now, and I hit some bugs. Maybe you can clear them up for me.

1. In the function call, `def intersection(pre,i=0,point=0,count=0,result=dt):`, `dt` isn't defined. What should it be?
2. On the fourth line, `i<0` - the default value of `i` is zero so, unless `i` is given a value on calling the function, this piece of code will never run.
3. I notice that the file being read and the file being written are the same: `../data/result.csv` - is this correct?
4. There's another undefined variable, `demand`, on line 14. Can you fill that in?

Let's see where we are after that.

Comment: dt is the csv file which has the larger data which i had exported using pd.read_csv() outside this function and given it as result=dt when user doesn't give any inputs(user will never give this input it will only give the pre) it will take dt data for first run and result of that first run is stored in result.csv after that dt data is replaced by result.csv data and function runs and gives output after its last run.

Comment: for your second question its 0<i which means it will not read result.csv file when the function would be running for the first time because at that time result.csv doesn't exist it will be created after first run and after that the updated result.csv will be imported and replaced by dt data and function will run on that particular data.

Comment: OK. I still need to know what the `demand` variable is. I'm trying to run your code on my local machine. I get a `NameError` when I get to line 14, because it doesn't know what `demand` is. So that's where we're currently stuck.

Comment: demand is again like a dt in which their is the value of demand values, it is variable in which demand.csv has been imported globally.

Comment: I’m sorry Aryaman. There are just too many parts in this for me to keep track of. My only suggestion now is not use one single function to do all you’re trying to do here. Maybe break it up into two or three different functions, and see if you can make it work that way. Best of luck.